# Advice on this script

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have no knowledge of any sort of coding/ computer languages and need help using this script for a flash sale.

```
setInterval(function() { 
    var m = Math.floor((new Date).getTime()/1000); 
    if(m == '1476693000000') { 
        document.getElementsByTagName('a')[43].click(); 
    } 
    else { 
        console.log("Script Activated…"); 
    } 
},10);
```

My question is what does this script 'really' do and is there any way to further improve it to enhance chances of buying the desired product?

This script has been described to be used for a flash sale on Mi India website and has been sourced from

http://trickweek.com/mi-rs-1-flash-sale-script-trick-buy-successfully-redmi-note3-mi4-rs-1/

Answer (score 0):

**It appears**, that your script waits for a described time (2PM today) and once your system's time is 2PM it clicks on a specific link.

In this code, this line is

```
var m=Math.floor((new Date).getTime()/1000);
```

is unnecessary, erroneous and should be replaced by

```
var m=(new Date).getTime();
```

since it is later comparing `m` with an actual millisecond value.

Also, **setInterval**

It takes two parameters - callback handler and millisecond value.

It invokes the callback handler every 10 milliseconds.

Comment: True, the original code is wrong because it's off by a factor of 1000, but so is your simplified version, because it gives you only a 10% chance of ever matching the specified time. (You're checking for an exact millisecond match but only doing that every 10 milliseconds.)

Answer (score 0):

The `setInterval` executes what is inside the function body every 10 milliseconds.
Var `m` gets the largest integer less than or equal to what is inside parenthesis.
Then goes the if condition to check if `m` equals `1476693000000` then the 43rd (starting from 0) element (tag) `a` gets found and clicked. If the `if` condition fails the `else` condition gets executed which prints to console log `Script Activated…`.

Answer (score 0):

The logic is simple. He is checking the flash sale time for every 10 milliseconds. Once the time reached, he is getting the "Add to cart" button on the page and clicking it dynamically.

I will explain you clearly.

**For Example:**

Mi mobiles flash sale is going to start on **17th October, 2016 at 2pm** exactly. So, through javascript, he is checking the current time reached the expected time or not.

Usually, we cannot compare directly date with another date. So, we need to convert the date with time into most accurate time i.e, into milliseconds. so we can get the flash sale date's timestamp(time in milliseconds)..

```
var flashSaleTime = new Date("2016/10/17 02:00:00:000 PM").getTime();
```

Note: In Javascript, Default date format is `YYYY/MM/DD` and `getTime()` methods returns date in milliseconds.

So, We need to check the current time(in milliseconds) reached falshSaleTime, We need to click the Add To Cart button dynamically.

```
var flashSaleTime = new Date("2016/10/17 02:00:00:000 PM").getTime();
setInterval(function(){
    var currentTime = Math.floor((new Date).getTime()/1000);
    if(currentTime*1000 === flashSaleTime){
        document.getElementsByTagName('a')[43].click();
    }
},10);
```

here, setInterval function check the condition for every 10 milliseconds.
So, once current time reaches the target time, we are getting reference to the button and triggering click on the button.